# Clang LLVM 1.0 Error objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsstring

I'm a beginner developer. I'and stopped with this error about:

```
Clang LLVM 1.0 Error
Expected ':'

line:  [pipe fileHandleForReading availableData]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
- (NSInteger)sizeOfItemAtPath:(NSString*)path {
    BOOL isdir;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path isDirectory:&isdir];
    if (isdir) {
        NSPipe *pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
        NSTask *t = [[[NSTask alloc] init] autorelease];
        [t setLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/du"];
        [t setArguments:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"-k", @"-d", @"0", path, nil]]; 

        [t setStandardOutput:pipe];
        [t setStandardError:[NSPipe pipe]]; 
        [t launch];
        [t waitUntilExit];

        NSString *sizeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[pipe fileHandleForReading availableData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
        sizeString = [[sizeString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "] objectAtIndex:0];
        BOOL bytes;
        bytes = [sizeString longLongValue]*1024;
    }
    else {
        BOOL bytes;
        bytes = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:path error:nil] fileSize];
    }
    BOOL bytes;
    return bytes;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `]`: it must be

```
[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData]
```

The whole line needs to look like this:

```
NSString *sizeString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] autorelease];
```

Also, your method will return garbage. That is because you've defined `bytes` three times: once in the `if` branch, once in the `else` branch and once in the enclosing method body. The return value will be taken from the last one, but this one is initialized. Not only that, but you're using the wrong type: it must be a `NSInteger bytes;`, not `BOOL bytes;`. You need to put the definition at the start of the method and remove all other definitions, the variable may exist only once.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[pipe fileHandleForReading] availableData]
```